# clear or reset all asp .net label's text value using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to clear or reset ALL asp.net label's text value on web page dynamically by finding them without using id

I am finding and setting the text for textbox fields as `$('.divclassname').find('input:text, input:password, input:file, textarea').val('');`

so how can I do this for ASP:LABEL controls

Answer (score 2):

`<asp:label />` will render as a `<label/>` if it is bind to any input field(set for attribute), otherwise it will render as `<span/>` So it is not good practice to remove all the label text or span texts. if you want to do so `$("label").empty()` will do the job. but I would suggest you to use a css class for all the `<asp:label />` tags and cleat text using following code

```
$(".className").empty();
```

Comment: Using class name I am able to do it THANK YOU so much Chamika Sandamal

Comment: If it is working for you, way of thanking is accept and up vote :)